# SQLplus client crash from remote machine oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener

I have oracle 11g XE everything running well except that I can't connect to oracle via SQLplus client from remote mashine.

My server running centos with oracle 11g XE.

My **listener.ora** file looks like: 
cat /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/**listener.ora**

> listener.ora Network Configuration File:
>
> SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
>       (SID_DESC =
>         (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
>         (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
>         (PROGRAM = extproc)
>       )   )
>
> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>       (DESCRIPTION =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername.domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
>       )   )
>
> DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

My tnsnames.ora looks like:

> XE =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername)(PORT = 1521))
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>         (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
>       )   )
>
> EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SID = PLSExtProc)
>         (PRESENTATION = RO)
>       )   )
>
> ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =    (DESCRIPTION = 
>       (ADDRESS_LIST = 
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
>       ) 
>       (CONNECT_DATA = 
>         (SID = CLRExtProc) 
>         (PRESENTATION = RO) 
>       )    )

lsnrctl status shows:

-bash-4.1$ lsnrctl status

> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 21-MAR-2014
>   14:00:28
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE))) STATUS of
>   the LISTENER
>   ------------------------ Alias                     LISTENER Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production Start Date
>   21-MAR-2014 13:39:10 Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 21 min. 18
>   sec Trace Level               off Security                  ON: Local
>   OS Authentication SNMP                      OFF Default Service
>   XE Listener Parameter File
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora Listener
>   Log File
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/venera/listener/alert/log.xml
>   Listening Endpoints Summary...
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=servername.domain.com)(PORT=1521)))
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=servername.domain.com)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
>   Services Summary... Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).   Instance
>   "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>   Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).   Instance "XE", status READY, has 1
>   handler(s) for this service... Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
>   Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... The
>   command completed successfully

File /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/venera/listener/alert/log.xml when I try to connect:

> 21-MAR-2014 14:00:03 * service_update * XE * 0   
>    
>   WARNING: Subscription for node down event still pending  
>     
>   21-MAR-2014 14:00:28 *
>   (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=servername.domain.com)(USER=oracle))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=186647040))
>   * status * 0     
>   21-MAR-2014 14:00:33 * service_update * XE * 0   
>    
>   21-MAR-2014 14:04:09 *
>   (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\ORANT\BIN\PLUS80W.EXE)(HOST=client_name)(USER=client_username)))
>   * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=REMTE_IP)(PORT=56366)) * establish * XE * 0

my /etc/hosts looks like:

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain
>   localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
>   192.168.100.70    servername.domain.com servername

I have NAT and open port 1521

in /**etc/sysconfig/iptables**

> -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT

Btw I can connect to oracle local:

-bash-4.1$ sqlplus system@XE

> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri Mar 21 14:19:07 2014
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Enter password:
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 -
>   64bit Production
>
> SQL>

I also try to run sqlplus as administrator. No luck. Any idea?

UPDATE CLIENT SITE:

C:\Users\ClientUsername>tnsping80 venera

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 8.0.6.3.0 - Production on 21-MAR-20
14 14:27:17

(c) Copyright 1997 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to contact (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=servername.domain.com)(PORT=152
1))
OK (80 msec)

Comment: Connecting to Oracle Database 11g from Oracle Client 8 will not work. Upgrade your client to 11g.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for Oracle Client 8 connecting to Oracle Database 11g

[image]

You need to upgrade your client.